# Fetching data keys from an api data set

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am struggling to parse data from my api result. I need to return a number from my getDailyRate function below. My code -

```
export type DailyRateType = {
  'success': boolean;
  'user' : string;
  'quotes' : object;
}

export const getDailyRate = (day:string):number =>
{
    let data = fetchDailyRates()
    let quotes = data.quotes; //Gives error that 'quotes' doesnt exist in Promise<DailyRateType[]>
    let quotes = data['quotes']; //Gives error similar to above
    console.log(data); // prints out promise
}

const fetchDailyRates = async (): Promise<DailyRateType[]> => 
      await (await fetch('http://myapilayer.net?format=1')).json();
```

However, if I test using a fake data by creating another function like this below, it works fine. However, I need to get it working with API data.

```
cons fetchDailyRates_v2 = (): DailyRateType[] => {
    return [
        {
            success: true,
            user: 'Admin',
            quotes: {
                'day1': 5.5,
                'day2': 5.8,
                'day3': 5.4,
            }
        }
    ];
}
```

**UPDATE**

As per suggestions below, I added asyc/await to getDailyRate:

```
export const getDailyRate = async (day:string) =>
{
    let data = await fetchDailyRates();
    let quotes = data['quotes']; 
    //Gives error - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

    console.log(data); // prints out promise
return 1;
}
```

Issues with this update -

1. Adding async/await creates another issue and asks me to remove 'number' type from the function as it becomes a Promise
2. The return type becomes Promise - I need it to be number only. So, if I just return number value (1 or 2). The return type becomes Promise and I try to assing this value to another place ... get this error "Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'number'."

Comment: Your getDailyRate function must be async and you must use await for fetchDailyRates function (because it's return Promise) then use data.

Comment: Hi, its async and using away. You can see that in the code above.

Comment: my mean: const getDailyRate = async (day: string) => { let data = await fetchDailyRates(); console.log(data); }

Comment: @MHP I tried aysn and await but still getting error. Also the getDailyRate return type has become Promise<number> .. I just wanted it to be a number only. I will update my code above to show what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use from result of an **asynchronous** function like as **synchronous** function, in the other hand when have **Promise** your desired type must be return by Promise (or don't specify type and it's consider any). I will show below with another way by custom hooks maybe useful for you:

```js
//import required packages

export type DailyRateType = {
  success: boolean;
  user: string;
  quotes: object;
};

export const useLazyQuery = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  const [data, setData] = React.useState([] as DailyRateType[]);

  const _request = async = () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const reponsedJson = await (await fetch('http://myapilayer.net?format=1')).json();

      console.log(data); //optional

      setData(reponsedJson);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  return [_request, {loading, data}];
}
```

And according to your response schema (fetchDailyRates_v2) for example in order to accessing to quotes in first element, you should use like **data?.[0]?.quotes** from that.

Comment: Sorry how do I use it? My idea was to create a file api.ts and import in App.tsx... in api.ts, I created two functions in it. One to actually fetch data from the api fetchDailyRatesFromAPI() .... The second helper function getDailyRate recieves a key parameter (1, 2, 3) .... then I look up in the quotes e.g. data[quote]['day'+key] and return it's number value. Hope that makes sense. There maybe more efficient way to do it but I am a learner at the moment.

Comment: Everywhere you want to use that just need import the above hook (in your functional component) and write "const [getDailyRate, {data, loading}] = useLazyQuery ();" so you can call  getDailyRate in **useEffect** and handle response by loading and data , lt's one of the best and clear approach with reusable ability to implementing request and you can write your another requests from this way.

Comment: I couldn't make use of your code but thanks for showing me how hooks works. I managed to use "useEffect" alone to fetch data and manipulate the way I want. Thx

Comment: Glad I was able to help, good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should use async/await for `getDailyRate`,Check this:

```
export type DailyRateType = {
  success: boolean;
  user: string;
  quotes: object;
};

async function getDailyRate(day: string): number {
  let data = await fetchDailyRates();
  let quotes = data?.['quotes']; 
  console.log(data, quotes);
  return 1
}

const fetchDailyRates = async (): Promise<DailyRateType[]> =>
  await (await fetch('http://myapilayer.net?format=1')).json();
```

at the and you need to call `getDailyRate`like below:

`await getDailyRate()`
**Update**
I've added a test with jsonplaceholder data:

```
async function getDailyRate(day: string): Promise<number> {
  let data = await fetchDailyRates();
  let userId = data?.['userId'];
  console.log(userId, ` <--- userId ----`);
  return 1;
}

const fetchDailyRates = async (): Promise<DailyRateType[]> =>
  await (await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')).json();


  const test = async () => {
    let temp: number = 1;
    temp = await getDailyRate('1'); // this is not complaining about the type
  };
```

Comment: Sorry but could you show me arrow notation for getDailyRate please

Comment: what do you mean, I've updated the answer please check it?

Comment: Please check my update in my question.

Comment: Yes, it's true and it means you return a promise that returns a number what is the problem with it?

Comment: Two issues here. let quotes = data?.['quotes'] still giving error. Second issue is that it doesn't just return number it returns Promise<number>

Comment: Updated the answer please check

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just simplified my code by putting it altogether in "useEffect"